# Mp4 image texture transparency

Tags: animation, texturing, image

So I'm trying to use an animated texture that requires transparency but with the Gif format not supported I'm having some issues with it, is there any way to sort of chroma key the unwanted parts of an mp4 in shaders and make them transparent? thanks in advance.